# Apache ServiceMix 7, ScalaDSL, No component found with scheme: jetty

Tags: java, scala, apache-camel, osgi, apache-karaf

I've created a very basic bundle using Scala for use in Camel and Karaf.  When I install my bundle in Apache ServiceMix 7.0.0 / Karaf, the bundle will resolve but not start. When I check the logs I get the message:  No component found with scheme: jetty

A thorough search for this problems only yields answers referring to making sure camel-jetty is included in the pom.xml.

I have done this, but unfortunately it still isn't working..

My Pom dependencies are (among others):

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-jetty-common</artifactId>
      <version>2.16.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-jetty9</artifactId>
      <version>2.16.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-jetty</artifactId>
      <version>2.16.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

The code in Scala is very basic:

```
   val netStart = "jetty:http://localhost:8882/userdata"
   val netEnd = "file:scala/netoutput"

   netStart ==> {
    as (classOf[Person])
    to (netEnd)
   }
```

and finally the list of referred components as shown in the Karaf web console is

```
Imported Packages   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind,version=2.8.2 from com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind (268)
com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala,version=2.8.2 from com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jackson.module.scala (246)
org.apache.camel,version=2.16.3 from org.apache.camel.camel-core (43)
org.apache.camel.builder,version=2.16.3 from org.apache.camel.camel-core (43)
org.apache.camel.component.jetty,version=2.16.3 from org.apache.camel.camel-jetty-common (270)
org.apache.camel.component.jetty9,version=2.16.3 from org.apache.camel.camel-jetty9 (271)
org.apache.camel.main,version=2.16.3 from org.apache.camel.camel-core (43)
org.apache.camel.scala.dsl,version=2.16.3 from org.apache.camel.camel-scala (220)
org.apache.camel.scala.dsl.builder,version=2.16.3 from org.apache.camel.camel-scala (220)
org.apache.camel.spi,version=2.16.3 from org.apache.camel.camel-core (43)
org.apache.camel.support,version=2.16.3 from org.apache.camel.camel-core (43)
org.osgi.framework,version=1.8.0 from org.apache.felix.framework (0)
scala,version=2.11.7.v20150622-112736-1fbce4612c from org.scala-lang.scala-library (213)
scala.collection,version=2.11.7.v20150622-112736-1fbce4612c from org.scala-lang.scala-library (213)
scala.collection.mutable,version=2.11.7.v20150622-112736-1fbce4612c from org.scala-lang.scala-library (213)
scala.reflect,version=2.11.7.v20150622-112736-1fbce4612c from org.scala-lang.scala-library (213)
scala.runtime,version=2.11.7.v20150622-112736-1fbce4612c from org.scala-lang.scala-library (213)
Manifest Headers    Bnd-LastModified: 1474031034895
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_91
Built-By: sander
Bundle-Activator: com.focuscura.servicemix.spielerei.MyRouteMain
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: MyFirstDSL
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.focuscura.servicemix.spielerei.my-first-dsl
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Export-Package: com.focuscura.servicemix.spielerei; uses:="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind, org.apache.camel, org.apache.camel.builder, org.apache.camel.component.jetty, org.apache.camel.component.jetty9, org.apache.camel.scala.dsl.builder, org.apache.camel.support, org.osgi.framework, scala, scala.collection, scala.reflect, scala.runtime"; version="1.0.0"
Import-Package: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind; version="[2.8, 3)", com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala; version="[2.8, 3)", org.apache.camel; version="[2.16, 3)", org.apache.camel.builder; version="[2.16, 3)", org.apache.camel.component.jetty; version="[2.16, 3)", org.apache.camel.component.jetty9; version="[2.16, 3)", org.apache.camel.main; version="[2.16, 3)", org.apache.camel.scala.dsl; version="[2.16, 3)", org.apache.camel.scala.dsl.builder; version="[2.16, 3)", org.apache.camel.spi; version="[2.16, 3)", org.apache.camel.support; version="[2.16, 3)", org.osgi.framework; version="[1.8, 2)", scala; version="[2.11, 3)", scala.collection; version="[2.11, 3)", scala.collection.mutable; version="[2.11, 3)", scala.reflect; version="[2.11, 3)", scala.runtime; version="[2.11, 3)"
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6))"
Tool: Bnd-3.0.0.201509101326
```

I have installed the camel-jetty9 feature and as a test I've created a blueprint route in xml that also uses a jetty route and that works fine.

Any help as to why ServiceMix / Karaf / Camel keeps insisting it cannot find jetty:html:?

Much thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had an issue similar to this and it was caused by an issue with the Camel version and the Jetty version not working together. Camel has not yet been updated to work with Jetty 9 and only works with Jetty 8.

If you roll back to Service Mix 6.1.x then you may find the issue resolves itself as it did in our case.

For more information on the versioning see http://servicemix.apache.org/community/releases-schedule.html

EDIT: Camel 2.18 will be fixing these issues but Service Mix 7 only uses 2.16

Source: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-9689

Comment: In the end I wasn't able to fix this.  Also on ServiceMix 6.1 it couldn't find the Jetty component. In the end I ditched the ScalaDSL altogether and defined my route using Blueprint. That works nicely in ServiceMix 7.0 (needed to reference Jetty 9 as Jetty8 resulted in a NullPointerException.